# What can be the Test Cases for one column update in data warehouse/ETL table

Tags: database, testing, etl, data-warehouse, testcase

We have a table in which value of one column (EMP_CD) is updated from '~' to 1 for some selected records(based on filter conditions).

Now, I am wondering what can be the test cases for this scenario. So far I figured out the following two -

1. All the records meeting selection criteria should have EMP_CD=1
2. All the records which don't meet selection criteria should have EMP_CD = EMP_CD of Backup( before update table)

Any other things which I should test for this scenario?

Comment: Have you considered moving this question to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Should the column EMP_CD  be updated to 1 only if it contains '~'?
If so, then you could try to have some records that match the filter but have different values like:
- nothing
- random string
- ~something
=> and check that those records are not updated

Comment: Yes! Their are certain conditions to identify the impacted records and EMP_CD='~' is one of them. I did add a test case where I am checking the all impacted records having EMP_CD<>1
Thanks for responding :)